# Memory Card to USB IC?

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, sd, microsd

Today I purchased a USB memory card reader. I cracked it open and saw that it basically only has an AU6477CL IC, which is based on the AU6370, which is a chip which takes SD/MMC/etc pins as input and acts as a USB driver for a computer to do i/o on the card. [Here is the datasheet for the AU6370](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/218991/ETC2/AU6370.html).

Where can I buy one of these things? It seems like every card reader in the universe is driven by one of these ICs, but short of buying 50,000 from alibaba (maybe), I can't find them anywhere.

Alternately, does anyone know of equivalent ICs which perform similar functions? Generically, what would I be searching for?

For hobbyists, is the best option really to use an AVR/PIC to write our own code (or existing libraries) if we were to create our own memory card reader?

Comment: Try to use the MAX14502, which is available at Mouser

Comment: Unfortunately, the MAX14502 is now [NRND](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/MAX14502.html/tb_tab3) and one variants are EOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cheapest way of getting the part is by buying a card reader from your favorite eBay Hong Kong vendor.

I was involved in purchasing AU6350s for a project.  The process involved lots of transcontinental communications, purchase orders, international wire transfers, and shipping accounts.  The developer board was about $150 if I remember correctly.  The Alcor people are nice, but there is just a lot of bureaucracy.

The Microchip USB stack has a card reader as one of their example projects.  It works fine, but is very slow compared to the dedicated chip.  About 50 times slower by my memory.

Comment: I would speculate that Microchip is using the SD card in MMC mode, to avoid having to pay the SD consortium licensing fees.

Comment: Yes, they are using the SPI interface.  But they are also only full-speed USB, where the Alcor chip is hi-speed.

Comment: MMC mode is significantly slower than true SD-mode.

Comment: Interesting - I had no idea that such a common IC could be so difficult to procure! Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same question, and ended up finding this.

I've found the [GL823](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Genesys-Logic-GL823_C48653.pdf) which (currently) costs about a quarter (USD; in qty 10) from [LCSC](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Others_Genesys-Logic_GL823K-HCY04_Genesys-Logic-GL823K-HCY04_C284879.html).  I even came across a [simple schematic](https://web.archive.org/web/20190815235540/https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/25352879/T21leaXwNaXXXXXXXX_!!25352879.jpg) (none in the datasheet), which shows it to likely be a real one chip solution.